Windows not booting up after Ubuntu installation
I recently installed Ubuntu 24.04 L.T.S. I had a lot of problems during installation but now, I just can't boot up windows. Even if i give it top priority through BIOS, Ubuntu somehow keeps opening. I'm not shown the choice of choosing which OS i want to use. I have tried almost everything. from ChatGPT to shady websites and forums. I have a Lenovo Ideapad 3 computer by the way.
This is like, really urgent. I have tons of important files on Windows, I can't access them through Ubuntu and I'm just afraid I'll lose them forever. About wiping out Windows, I can see the Windows booloader at the BIOS priority selector, but even if I put it first, Ubuntu is the one to load instead of Windows
Edit: As David asked, all problems during installation were resolved. I selected to install Ubuntu besides, not instead of, my current OS, Windows 11. About wiping out Windows, Windows bootloader is visible in the priority list, but Ubuntu no matter what comes first

Good chance you wiped out Windows when you installed Ubuntu. If Windows was installed and working and Ubuntu was installed correctly it would have prompted to install besides the existing OS. Did you get that prompt during the Ubuntu install? You said there were problems during the Ubuntu install, are we supposed to guess what they were and how you fix them? Please edit the question and add the missing info.

How you resolved the "problems" you had installing may make a huge differnce. Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed. Use often updated ppa version with your USB installer or any working install over somewhat older ISO.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair &
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/ If data if really valuable, just about everyone says you must have backups. And many of us (me included) have learned that lesson the hard way. I had backup, but old.

Look oldfred, I just wanted to try Linux. The problem was Ubuntu was repeatedly asking me to install while I already had and an unexpected error during installation. To be honest, I installed it next to the bootloader, not the USB stick. I believe it's the computer's problem since i followed a tutorial

Also, to be honest, and sorry about that, I have no idea what you mean by Boot info summary. Is it like some kind of output during installation?

Please read this page for how to generate the bootinfo report. It would also help if you could show the current situation with your disks. Do you see the Windows disk from Ubuntu? Can you access its files? At the end of the day though, we probably won't be able to help you since your problem is with Windows, not with Ubuntu. You might want to delete this and ask instead on [su] where they have Windows knowledge.

I can't access the Windows files, not through Ubuntu file explorer at least. I can't find the Window disk, no matter how many commands i ran. Im going to read the page now. Thanks for your time everyone

I think i have the boot info link. https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/wwMgYWySpT/

Does this answer your question? Unable to boot into Windows after installing Ubuntu, how to fix?

Unfortunately no. I'm considering taking it to an expert who knows better than me

NEVERMIND I FIXED IT YALL
i made a bootable windows usb with another computer and booted it from there

Not a fix. What you are saying is you made a new Windows install. How is that a fix?

Since it fixed the problem, it's considered a fix

@DavidDE With self-answered questions I almost always agree with the author's answer, except that I don't believe that the Earth is flat.
